# Check if one date is after another?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am trying to check if one datetime is after another, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am simply using the `>=` operator, but it is not working as expected?

Here is the code:

```
public function hasCompleted() {
    return Carbon::parse($this->withdrawable_at) >= Carbon::now();
}
```

I am using the Carbon package, a DateTime PHP library found [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

It seems to return true for the following data, which it shouldn't.

```
2020-11-13 02:59:04, 2020-11-12 15:17:31
```

Comment: What's the value of `$this->withdrawable_at` ? Does parsing it return a Carbon instance with the date+time that you'd expect?

Comment: Data: `2020-11-13 02:59:04, 2020-11-12 15:17:31`, the first one being withdrawable_at

Comment: I'm confused - why wouldn't you expect it to return true for that data? 2020-11-13 is *after* 2020-11-12, which is what the `>=` operator is testing

Comment: @iainn I don't expect it to return true, read my latest question edit.

Comment: I have read it - I'm asking you *why* you expect that. You're comparing 2020-11-13 and 2020-11-12. The first date is **after** the second, so it's returning true.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon has it's own methods for it which are called isAfter and isBefore

```
    public function hasCompleted() {
    return Carbon::parse($this->withdrawable_at)->isAfter(Carbon::now());
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't explain why it doesn't work with the `>=` operator, this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: So you have to rename your question. You did not answer why exactly the operator >= is not working correctly.

Comment: This also returns true for the following data: `2020-11-13 02:59:04, 2020-11-12 15:17:31`, which it shouldn't.

Comment: a boolean only has two values, therefor the why can only be one thing.

Comment: It is true because 2020-11-13 IS AFTER 2020-11-12

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=` to compare `DateTime` objects so it also work perfectly with `Carbon` instances:

```
var_dump(Carbon::parse('2020-11-13 02:59:04') >= Carbon::parse('2020-11-12 15:17:31'));
var_dump(Carbon::parse('2020-11-12 15:17:31') >= Carbon::parse('2020-11-13 02:59:04'));
```

Output `true`, then `false`, (in this case because 13 > 12) that's the expected behavior. Newest dates are considered greater than oldest dates. I find it pretty intuitive, but if it's not enough explicit for you, you can use `isAfter` / `isBefore`, just be aware, those methods just use `>` and `<` internaly.